# Custom of singing Aishes Chayil before kiddush

Tags: minhag, provenance, shabbat-songs, leil-shabbat, aishes-chayil

It [seems](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uDWS9qdlGJ8) that not everyone [always] sang/sings Aishes Chayil with Sholom Aleichem at the Friday night Shabbos table.

When and how did the custom of singing Aishes Chayil at the table begin? Who follows it--or rather, who doesn't?

Comment: Closely related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/987. Somewhat related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1798 and http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/45869.

Comment: http://shut.moreshet.co.il/shut2.asp?id=51623

Comment: @GershonGold Can't read it, sorry. Summary?

Comment: It isn't an answer. He writes that it most likely originated from the Arizal.

Comment: @GershonGold I wonder, then, why the people in my video weren't singing it?

Comment: I sing Shalom Aleichem and Aishes Chayil in my living room after Maariv before kiddush in my "shul" with my family, and not at the Shabbos table. :) :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The custom of saying Eshet Hayil on Friday night does not seem universal among Teimani Jews. [R. Qafih](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yosef_Qafih) makes no mention of it in his discussion of Friday night practices in Yemen (Halikhot Teiman (1969) pg. 5). The Teimani Siddur *Siah Yerushalayim* (pg. 48) states that some add Eshet Hayil.

Based (partially) [this article](http://forum.otzar.org/forums/download/file.php?id=22466), the practice was popularised by the work *Tikkunei Shabbat* (373) presenting the ideas of the [Arizal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isaac_Luria) (mid 16th cent.). It is in turn quoted verbatim in the [controversial](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/86707/8775) but influential [Hemdat Yamim](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%97%D7%9E%D7%93%D7%AA_%D7%99%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%9D_(%D7%A1%D7%A4%D7%A8)) (17th cent.) [here](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/reader/reader.aspx?sfid=49704#p=409&fitMode=fitwidth&hlts=&ocr=%25u05D0%25u05E9%25u05EA%20%25u05D7%25u05D9%25u05DC%20%25u05DE%25u05E8%25u05D0%25u05E9%25u05D4). It was further referenced by [Shelah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isaiah_Horowitz) (late 16th-17th century) over [here](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/reader/reader.aspx?sfid=19726#p=1&fitMode=fitwidth&hlts=&ocr=%25u05D0%25u05E9%25u05EA%20%25u05D7%25u05D9%25u05DC%20%25u05DE%25u05E8%25u05D0%25u05E9%25u05D4), [R. Yaakov Emden](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacob_Emden) (18th cent.) [here](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/reader/reader.aspx?sfid=42760#p=1&fitMode=fitwidth&hlts=&ocr=%25u05D0%25u05E9%25u05EA%20%25u05D7%25u05D9%25u05DC%20%25u05DE%25u05E8%25u05D0%25u05E9%25u05D4), [R. Zaddok Hakohen of Lublin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zadok_HaKohen) (mid 19th cent.) (P'ri Tsadik: Parashat Hayei Sarah: 1), [Ben Ish Hai](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yosef_Hayyim) (e.g. Rav P'alim (Vol. IV: Sod Yesharim: 16) (late 19th cent.) and many others.